# Is it necessary to connect 2 my video cards by SLI if I want to place them on my motherboard and use for CUDA computing?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda

I'm building little CPU/GPU cluster for my home needs. This cluster Im using for CUDA computing. I have 3 PCs and each of it has 1 videocard. I want to modify one of them. I want to buy 2 videocards and a new motherboard. Is is necessary to buy SLI-supported videocards to run CUDA to compute with the power of 2 video cards or can I  buy nonSLI-supported video cards for computing? (I have not got much money). I must be sure that my app can run on multi GPU PC(thats why I dont want to spent much money on GPU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SLI connection is not used by CUDA. If you have two cards, they will appear as two devices in CUDA, even if they are connected with SLI. So, your CUDA application has to handle each GPU individually.